# Facebook og:title and og:site_name are never updated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Our Facebook application is titled "Home Page" by Facebook, which is not the preferred name for our application! We've tried to update the og meta tags to no avail. We've checked out the debug page, trying to force a refresh. Other meta tags like og:description do update successfully, but og:title and og:sitename do not. The unix timestamp is always fresh and the scraper shows the correct information, i.e.:

```
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=[our site url]

Meta Tag: meta property="og:title" content="*old title that does not update*" ...

Meta Tag: meta property="og:site_name" content="*old title that does not update*" ...

vs: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=[our site url]
```

where we see:

```
meta id="FBItemTitle" property="og:title" content="*new title that we want*"...

meta id="SiteName" property="og:site_name" content="*new title that we want*"...
```

Is it possible that Facebook simply refuses to update title and site_name for site url's or canvas pages?

Comment: What's the URL or full response from the debugger?

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing the point, but have you visited https://developers.facebook.com/apps?  There you can click on your app, then select edit settings.  There you can edit your apps Canvas Url and Display name.  After saving, you'll get this message "Changes saved. Note that your changes may take several minutes to propagate to all servers.", so it may take awhile.

Comment: @phwd, here is the url from the debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=apps.facebook.com%2Flinksterapp - you can see the metatags for title and site_name are correct in the scraper's output. I also noticed that if I append anything to the url in the debugger, the title and site_name are corrected, and the timestamp is up to date. the only url that's incorrect is this one, which is the canvas url, which we cannot change because it's our namespace.

Comment: @BrentLingle, I meant to say canvas *page*. this is the only page that the graph has the wrong og:title and og:site_name for, which you set on your site, apart from the app's display name. the messed up thing is the scraper sees the correct tags, it's just not being updated in the graph.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't somewhere in your code that references "Home Page"

Comment: "Home Page" exists nowhere on the FB app page or on our site.As you can see there on the debug page, the scraper sees the correct title and site_name, it simply doesn't update in the Graph. Changes to og:description however are reflected immediately.